# My -ing (possessive form + -ing) vs. me ing (object form + -ing)

Tags: gerunds, present-participles

(a) We filter out information that the brain deprioritizes *without **our** knowing it*.
(b)We filter out information that the brain deprioritizes *without **us** knowing it.*

I came across the sentence (a) above, modified for clarification.
I wonder it is possible to use "us," as in sentence (b), instead of "our," as in (a).
If possible, is there any semantic difference between these two sentences?
Could [my(her, their, etc.) + -ing form] and [me (her, them, etc.) + -ing form] in a sentence always be used interchangeably with little or no difference in meaning?
Grammatically, is the phrase "our knowing it" in sentence (a) considered a present participle or gerund?
I know both of the following sentences are just fine, with (c) a more formal tone.
(c) Do you mind **my** smoking?
(d) Do you mind **me** smoking?
Generally, however, I have no idea what exactly is semantically different between "my + -ing form" and "me + -ing form," nor the underlying grammatical logic.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes: they are interchangeable, and no: there are no semantic differences other than, as you say, the form with a genitive pronoun is a tad more formal. Trad grammar calls "our knowing it" /"my smoking" gerund clauses.

Comment: Thanks. So, "without our/us knowing" is considered a gerund clause. I believe the possessive construction with -ing clauses is rarely seen in present-day English. How about this?

Comment: I haven't seen any recent statistics, so I'm not certain. Incidentally, be careful about your example (c). "Smoking" could be a noun or a verb -- see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

> [a] *We filter out information that the brain deprioritizes without **our***
>   *knowing it*.
>
> [b] *We filter out information that the brain deprioritizes without **us***
>   *knowing it*.

These are both fine and interchangeable. There are no semantic differences other than, as you suggest, that the construction with a genitive pronoun [a] is more formal.

The same applies to your other examples where both "me" and "my" are fine. But a note of caution:

[c] Do you mind my smoking?

Here, the syntactic status of "smoking" is strictly speaking ambiguous: it could be either a verb or a noun. The latter interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in *Do you mind my occasional smoking?*

Answer (score -1):

There is a different of politeness between me +ing form and my +ing form. It also reflects you are uneducated if you use me + -ing form

Comment: There's nothing ungrammatical about "Do you mind me smoking".